# Installing devtools fails because of dependency, but dependency is not available for the R version I have

Tags: r, linux

```
configure: error: 
---------------------------------------------
  OpenSSL library required

  Please install:
  libssl-dev (deb) or openssl-devel (rpm)
---------------------------------------------
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
 * removing ‘/home/udi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/git2r’
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
 * removing ‘/home/udi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/httr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
 * removing ‘/home/udi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/devtools’
```

However, when I try to install libssl-dev (I have Ubuntu 14.04.3) then I got the message "‘libssl-dev’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)".

Any idea what to do? Download a new R version or is there any other solution?

Comment: Umm, `libssl-dev` is not an R package. It's a linux package.

Comment: `libssl-dev` is a system package, not an R package. You have to install it in Ubuntu through `apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Comment: Oops, that's embarrassing. I did what you suggested and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is a system package - not a R package.  From the command line you can run

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

What fixes the problem in my Ubuntu is installing this:

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

It is not immediately apparent unless you do:

`install.packages("git2r")`

it will throw this error:

```
The zlib library that is required to build
   git2r was not found.

   Please install:
     zlib1g-dev (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     zlib-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
   and try again.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually help me on Ubuntu 18.04 – after installing that package I still get the same error.